# django celery asynchronous file saves to storage

Tags: django, django-models, celery, django-celery

So I want to asynchronously conduct file saves to django file storage. I've tried to achieve this by overwriting the default File System Storage class.

```py
import hashlib
import os
import uuid

import django.core.files.storage as storage
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.files import File


class DefaultStorage(storage.FileSystemStorage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DefaultStorage, self).__init__()

    @shared_task
    def _save(self, name, content):
        # need to encrypt file before saving
        return super(DefaultStorage, self)._save(name, content)

    @shared_task
    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        # need to decrypt before opening
        return File(open(self.path(name), mode))

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        # we return a hash of the file given,
        # in case we miss out on uniqueness, django calls
        # the get_alternative_name method
        dir_name, file_name = os.path.split(name)
        file_root, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)

        file_root = hashlib.md5(file_root.encode()).hexdigest()
        name = os.path.join(dir_name, file_root + file_ext)
        return super(DefaultStorage, self).get_available_name(name, max_length)

    def get_alternative_name(self, file_root, file_ext):
        # we insert a random uuid hex string into the given
        # file name before returning the same back
        return '%s%s%s' % (file_root, uuid.uuid4().hex, file_ext)

    def save(self, name, content, max_length=None):
        # override existing system storage save method
        # to ensure that we call the shared task and
        # utilize the distributed task queue celery offers
        has_chunks = hasattr(content, 'chunks')
        name = content.name if not name else name
        content = File(content, name) if not has_chunks else content
        name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)
        saved = self._save.delay(self, name, content)
        return saved

    def open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        # override existing system storage open method
        # to ensure that we call the shared task and
        # utilize the distributed task queue celery offers
        return self._open.delay(name, mode)
```

The idea is to override the existing `save` method to fire off the shared_task named `_save`. However, I am facing the following error while trying to do the same.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\api_backend\serializers\partial.py", line 32, in create
    return super(PartialUploadSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 939, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\api_backend\models\uploads.py", line 30, in save
    super(Upload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 754, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 792, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 935, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1341, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1341, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1291, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 307, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 87, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\api_backend\models\storage\default_storage.py", line 48, in save
    saved = self._save.delay(self, name, content)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 421, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 565, in apply_async
    **options
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 749, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\amqp.py", line 532, in send_task_message
    **properties
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 166, in publish
    compression, headers)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 249, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 53, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\exceptions.py", line 21, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 49, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\json.py", line 66, in dumps
    **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\PycharmProjects\cloud-server\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\json.py", line 55, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "C:\Users\iyapp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'DefaultStorage' is not JSON serializable
```

I believe I have found the source of the issue. It is because we cannot pass "file" objects as parameters to shared_task functions. If this is the case, then how can I send my file to the `_save` function?
Before sending, the file isn't saved yet. We need to save the file only after receiving.

Comment: P.S. my assumption might as well as be wrong. Maybe passing the file as a parameter isn't the actual reason for the error occurance

Comment: Is asynchronous file storage like this even possible in django?